# HighCharts contents misplacement/misalignment after maximizing the browser from restore?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have placed four charts in my application and one of them gets misaligned after the browser window is maximized from restore.
The chart box remains small and legends fall outside the box which never goes back to original position after maximize. The only difference in this chart is that grouped categories have been used.
Have tried in other browsers as well.

Please refer the below image for the issue.
[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor with the sample data which I could work on?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/78qogsaz/1/

Comment: added the code on jsfiddle. I am using the grid to display two charts next to each other like this.   
            <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6" id = "chart1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6" id = "chart2"></div>
            </div>

Comment: Thank you for reporting it, it seems like a regression to me. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14410

Comment: The issue has been moved here: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues/171